# Check whether given series is convergent or divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a_1$=$1$ and $a_{n+1}$=$\left(\frac{2+\cos(n)}{n^{1/2}}\right)a_n$.
>   Determine whether $\sum_n a_n$ converges or diverges.

I have one try as follows.
$2+\cos(n)\geq 1$ and since $a_n$ is positive I can write $a_{n-1}\left(\frac{2+\cos(n)}{n^{1/2}}\right)\geq \frac{a_{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}$... and so by comparison test I am claiming series is divergent..Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, your attempt is not conclusive. You show that $a_n \geq \frac{a_{n-1}}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ (you have a small mismatch in the index, but that's not a big deal), but by itself this does not lead to the conclusin you claim. Note that $a_n \geq \frac{a_{n-1}}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ and $a_n \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ are two *entirely different* things.

Actually, the series is *convergent*. Here is one could go to prove it, in two ways.

**Outline 1 (simple)**
Use the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). Indeed,

$$
\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert = \frac{2+\cos n}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{3}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$
and so...

**Outline 2 (complicated):**

- for all $n\geq 1$, $$0\leq a_n \leq b_n$$
  where $(b_n)_n$ is the sequence defined by $b_1=1$, and $b_{n+1} \stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}}b_n$.
- We have a closed-form for $b_n$, as $b_{n+1} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{3}{\sqrt{k}} = \frac{3^n}{\sqrt{n!}}$.
- By e.g. using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and comparison, this closed-form allows you to conclude that $\sum_n b_n$ converges.
- By comparison (using the first point), this then implies that $\sum_n a_n$ converges.

Comment: One can skip Stirling's and just use ratio test. $n!$ is way faster than $3^n$ to make that converge slower than a geometric series.

Comment: @arts True -- note that I wrote "e.g." (there are many ways to do so. If one knows Stirling's approximation, it's a quick way to do so, but by no means the simplests or only one).

Comment: (Added an extra, much simpler method to prove the convergence.)

Comment: Sorry but I just don't get from where $3^{n}$ and that $n!$ arrive...

Comment: @omkarGirkar $$\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{3}{\sqrt{k}} =  \frac{\prod_{k=1}^n3}{\prod_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}} = \frac{3^n}{\sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^n k}} = \frac{3^n}{\sqrt{n!}}$$

Comment: Ohh..thanks.Your outline 1 makes my life easy..I will try to understand outline 2 also..

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You have that

$$a_{n+1} = \left(\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(2+\cos(k))}{\sqrt{n!}} \right)$$

Then, the following inequalities hold true

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \le a_{n+1} \le \frac{3^n}{\sqrt{n!}} $$
Compare, and you will find if it diverges or converges.

Comment: Your first expression is not true. That's not what the recurrence relation gives...

Comment: Ops, thanks for pointing that out. I edited and written it correctly now!

Comment: Sorry,but your answer was bouncer for me!!any simple logic..